# Changing keyboard type for html textarea on iPad

Tags: ios, forms, input, keyboard, textarea

I'm writing a web application for iPad.
I know it's possible to change the type of keyboard displayed when an html **input** field is selected using:

```
Text: <input type="text" />
Telephone: <input type="tel" /> 
URL: <input type="url" /> 
Email: <input type="email" /> 
Zip Code: <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

the problem is that I have to use **textarea** instead of **input**. Is it possible to obtain the same result?

If not : is there any way to change the keyboard label for the ENTER key. At the moment the default label is "Return" and I would like to have "Send" (since it's a chat app).

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is plain html/css/javascript. This is not possible

Comment: Ok.Let's say I will use input instead of textarea. Among the possible keyboard types there is none with the ENTER key different from "Return" or "Go". How do I change it?

Comment: You can use a URL keyboard and make the input element quite large with css.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html shows the possible keyboards. You cannot customize these in any way to my knowledge, so a custom label for enter is out of the question

Comment: If you really want this, it is worth looking into making a native ios application.

Comment: Do you know if there is any protocol to implement as using UITextField? I could use it for setting UIReturnKeyType on the "send" button.

Answer (score 2):

if you use `<input title="Search">` the "enter" key is replaced by a "search" button, I haven't been able to find a listing of all the different combinations, but I'm sure there is one to you liking.

Note: The input must be inside a form element for this to work.

Comment: As of iOS8 it has to be wrapped by a `<form>` and the `action` attribute of the form has to be set too.