# change UIWebView input view with custom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, contenteditable, custom-keyboard

Is it possible to use a custom keyboard with editable UIWebView for rich text editing (by setting inputView property, like on UITextView) ? UIWebView inputView property seems to be readonly.

What we can do for such cases ? How we can override that. The option hidden textfield on custom web view won't help as it won't work perfectly.

Note that this applies to editable WebView content (having HTML attribute contentEditable="true"), not HTML input fields.

Comment: same question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270190/changing-keyboard-type-for-html-textarea-on-ipad

Comment: don't get why you feel "same question"

Comment: it also want to change keyboard in text box other then input tag

Comment: then sorry. this applies to contentEditable

Comment: also i just not need to change keyboard type. but custom view for keyboard. any help on that

Comment: Any success on this one?